# What is the difference in recommended code for putting device into deepsleep between ESP8266 and ESP32?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, esp32, sleep-mode

The following code is recommended to put an ESP8266 in deep sleep for 60 seconds:

```
ESP.deepSleep(60 * 1000000);
```

I use it on the `ESP32` it also works, but the recommended code for ESP32 is:

```
esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(60 * 1000000);
esp_deep_sleep_start();
```

Is there a difference between the two for the ESP32?

Answer (score 1):

With `ESP.deepsleep` you can't use different wakeup sources – only a timer:

```
void EspClass::deepSleep(uint32_t time_us)
{
    esp_deep_sleep(time_us);
}
```

Comment: Tnx. I only need a timer wake up for now.